# How to shutdown MongoDB Routing Server?

Tags: mongodb, shutdown, mongo-shell

```
./mongos --configdb mongodb0.test.net:27030,mongodb1.test.net:27030,mongodb2.test.net:27030 --port 27040 --logpath routing.log --fork
```

I run this script to setup my routing server.

For mongod, I can use --shutdown or enter to mongo and write db.shutdownServer() but it is not the case for mongos.

are there any ways to shutdown? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The routers (mongos) do not actually maintain any persisted data themselves. Instead all data is managed by separate `mongod` instances for the config servers or otherwise in members of the shards they are accessing.

As such can simply be shutdown with signal handling from the `kill` command.

For more information on tracking the `pid` for created processes see the [`--pidfilepath`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongos/#cmdoption--pidfilepath) option in the documentation.

Comment: thank you. I also think kill command is the only way. btw, I would like to request professional advices about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956722/spring-data-mongodb-how-to-config-more-than-one-routing-servers

Comment: @fmchan Well you can either do it that way or use other daemon management tools, but most methods will internally to the same thing